# Where do you put ActiveRecord callback classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop

Was going over the rails docs and came across the recommendation for [creating callback classes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#callback-classes) for ActiveRecord models. Though it does an excellent job in describing their usage it doesn't list where exactly to put them. What would be the most appropriate directory to do so?

Comment: I would suggest `app/models/callbacks/`

Comment: Thanks. I should have also asked: As far as naming, is it just to give them a plural class/file name? Although it looks as though in the example code it just seems a little awkward to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to create a folder in `app/models/callbacks/` and structure your files like following:

```
- app
  - models
    - callbacks
      user.rb
    user.rb
```

And then:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create ::Callbacks::User
  after_destroy ::Callbacks::User
  # we have to prepend :: here because it would try to refer to the namespace
  # ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks otherwise
end
```

&

```
module Callbacks
  module User
    # Warning: If you want to refer to the User model in there, you will have to
    # prepend it with `::` so it looks up from the root because this module has
    # the same name as the User model
    # ex: 
    #  ::User::SOME_CONSTANT
    # and not
    #  User::SOME_CONSTANT

    def self.after_create(user)
      ::Services::Emails::Welcome.enqueue!(user_id: user.id)
    end

    def self.after_destroy(user)
      ::Services::Emails::Goodbye.enqueue!(user_id: user.id)
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```

This is a simple structure using Service Objects as well.

Comment: I get `(uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks::User` when attempting to do an `after_save`.

Comment: Try using `after_create ::Callbacks::User` (notice the two `:` before `Callbacks`)

Comment: That did it but had to prepend the double colons in the callback declaration in user.rb: `after_create ::Callbacks::User`. My apologies if this is what you were referring to.